# How do I force a image I inserted in LaTeX right after the previous text?

Tags: formatting, latex

How can I force a image I inserted in LaTeX right after the previous text, and text afterwards will only show after that image, so what I mean is I don't want to have image out of nowhere in the middle of some random text.

Comment: This question would be much more useful if you included a minimal code showing **how** the image was _inserted in LaTeX right after the previous text_ ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the “float” package and then the [H] option for your figure.

```
\usepackage{float}

 ...

 \par some text


 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering              
 \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{images/flow-  chart.jpg}
 \caption{Flow chart of our text detection, tracking and motion analysis}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Wiki page for Floats, Figures, and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures) gives a listing of all specifiers for the figure environment. `[h]` "Place[s] the float here, i.e. approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)", but if you want it *exactly* where you place it in the text, then use the additional specifier `!`, which "Override[s] internal parameters LaTeX uses for determining "good" float positions." I typically use `[ht]`, because if the compiler determines that 'here' isn't a good place, then the top of the page should do.

Answer (score 0):

One of the mine hack
Using `~` and `\vspace`

```
\documentclass{article}

% packages
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

% detailes
\author{hacker}
\title{IA-3 Important questions RES}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Explain the working of open cycle OTEC with neat diagram ?
        \item [$\rightarrow$] ~\vspace{-1em}
                \begin{figure}[H]
                    \centering \includegraphics[scale=.5]{Open Cycle OTEC.png}
                    \caption{Schematic of the OTEC Open cycle}
                \end{figure}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item An open-cycle OTEC uses the warm ocean surface water as working fluid. It is a non-toxic and environment friendly fluid. 
            \item The major components of this system consists of evaporator, low-pressure turbine coupled with electrical generator, condenser,  non-condensable gas exhaust, and pumps.
            \item Evaporator used in an open-cycle system is a flash evaporator in which warm sea water instantly boils or flash in the chamber that has reduced pressure than atmosphere or vacuum. 
            \item It results in reduced vaporization pressure of warm sea water. 
            \item The low-pressure vapour (steam) expands in turbine to drive a coupled electrical generator to produce electricity.
            \item A portion of electricity generated is consumed in plants to run pumps and for other work, and the remaining large amount of electricity is stored as net electrical power.
            \item A large turbine is required to accommodate large volumetric flow rates of low-pressure steam, which is needed to generate electrical power, and is used with other plant components in a similar manner. 
            \item During vapourization process in an evaporator, oxygen, nitrogen, and carbon dioxide dissolved in sea water are separated with the help of deareater and are non-condensable.
            \item They are exhausted by non-condensable gas exhaust system. 
            \item Condenser is used to condense vapour or steam released from steam turbine is condensed by cold deep sea water and returned back to sea.
            \item If a condenser is used, condensed steam (desalinated water) remains separated from cold sea water and is pumped into marine culture ponds or back into the ocean. 
            \item To avoid leakage of air in atmosphere and to prevent abnormal operation of plants, perfect sealing of all components and piping systems is essential.
            \item The cooling water from the deep ocean which is at about 11$^\circ$, on reaching the condenser, its temperature rises to about 15$^\circ$, due to heat transfer between the progressively warmer outside water and cooling water inside the pipe.
            \item The warm surface water is continuously pumped into evaporator and cycle is repeated.
        \end{itemize}
        \item Explain the working of anderson cycle OTEC with neat diagram ?
        \item Explain the working of fuel cell with neat diagram ?
        \item Explain the concept of zero energy building ?
        \item Explain the pro and cons of using hydrogen as fuel.
        \item Explain electrolysis process with neat diagram ?
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```